# Can't find customers order and product ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woo-commerce with the membership and subscription extensions. I'm trying to display the expiration date of the current users subscription for which I need the subscription key to access it.

To find this key I need the product_id and order_id and (because these two values make up the key, "254_119" for example.). But when I try and access the current users order with

```
$order = new WC_Order(ID);
print_r($order);
```

The order data is empty, I tried to access the user_meta in the database as well before realising that it only contains shipping info and such.

Is it possible to access the current users most recent order? I've read that I may need to use

```
get_posts()
```

But I'm not sure of the parameters to access the data I require.

This doesn't seem to work either.

```
$customer_orders = get_posts($order_count);
```

Comment: global $woocommerce, $post;

$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then approach should be :

Get most **recent order** of **current User**.

```
/*Get most recent order of customer*/
$recent_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(), //Current user's id
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) );
```

Now as we have most recent order, we can get *`order_id`* from that order.

```
$order_id = $recent_orders[0]->ID; //Order Id
```

Now to get Products of that order, we can do as following :

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$cart_item = $order->get_items();//Get Cart Items of that order
```

Now we have both **`product_id`** and **`order_id`** so we can make a key :

```
foreach($cart_item as $item){
    echo "Product Name : ".$item['name'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Product Id : ".$item['product_id'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Your Key ".$order_id."_".$item['product_id'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

All Code together :

```
<?php 
    /*Get most recent order of customer*/
    $recent_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(), //Current user's id
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) );

    $order_id = $recent_orders[0]->ID; //Order Id
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    $cart_item = $order->get_items();//Get Cart Items of that order
    foreach($cart_item as $item){
        echo "Product Name : ".$item['name'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Product Id : ".$item['product_id'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Your Key ".$order_id."_".$item['product_id'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, works just like I needed, thank you very much!
I noticed that on the order received page I could echo out the order number and product ID, so from there I was going to save those two values into separate sessions and then use them on the page that I'm trying on. This solution is much nicer!

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore. $item['product_id'] is not there anymore